# Using Powershell Invoke-command, loading the -Computername variable from an external file doesn't work

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I have a script that uses the Invoke-Command to run a script on 19 different servers in parallel.  I have to supply a list of computer names with the `-ComputerName` parameter.

If I set up my variable like this:

```
$serverlist = "localhost","BRKAXHF10", "BRKAXHF12"
```

and issue the command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverlist -Filepath "$filepath\AOSAutomatedStartup.ps1" -ErrorAction Stop
```

It works exactly as I want.  The problem  is that if I try to build the variable $serverlist like this:

```
$serverlist = Get-content -path .\serverlist.txt
```

where serverlist.txt is a text file that contains:

localhost,BRKAXHF10,BRKAXHF12

or

I have also tried loading an array and then using:

```
$serverlist = [string]::Join(",",$array)
```

No matter what I try to make this more generic the only way I can get it to work is to explicitly load `$serverlist` in the script.

I have done the write-host to check the contents of the variable and it always looks fine.

The error I get is that there is an invalid name in the ComputerName list

Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: try to read it into array `[string[]]$serverlist = Get-Content -Path '.\serverlist.txt'`  or if it is CSV file then better way  `$serverlist = @(Import-CSV "serverlist.csv")`

Comment: String.Join takes an array and produces a single string. You want the opposite, take a single string (the content of the txt-file) and turn it into an array. You can do this with String.Split, so try  $serverlist.Split(",")

Comment: shouldn't `serverlist.txt is a text file that contains:localhost,BRKAXHF10,BRKAXHF12` be  `serverlist.txt is a text file that contains:"localhost","BRKAXHF10","BRKAXHF12"`?

Answer (score 0):

you are reading the file using `Get-Content` so a good practice would be to create the file using the "opposite" command `Set-Content` like

```
$serverlist = "localhost","BRKAXHF10", "BRKAXHF12"
$serverlist | Set-Content .\serverlist.txt
```

if you now read this file using `$serverlist = Get-Content .\serverlist.txt` it should work

you can now further inspect the file on how PowerShell expects a list (array) to be stored in a file and see that each server is in it's own line instead of a comma separated list